# Project compiles in intellij but not when exported

Tags: java, fxml

So my application runs and functions normally when I run it through intellij, but when I export the application it wont even launch. This is the Stack Trace I get.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at application.UIController.start(UIController.java:42)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Exception running application application.UIController

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the code that it is complaining about.

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    screen = stage;

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(UIController.class.getResource("/fxml/LoginFXML.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        loginController = loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 340, 487);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/application.css").toExternalForm());
        screen.setScene(scene);
        screen.show();
        screen.setResizable(false);
        screen.setTitle("Room Booking System");

        if (launched.equals(false)) {
            launched = true;
            Database_Control launchdb = new Database_Control();
            launchdb.launch();
        }



        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        screen.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - screen.getWidth()) / 2);
        screen.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - screen.getHeight()) / 2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It complains about a location not being set, so I tried

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();   loader.setLocation(UIController.class.getResource("/fxml/LoginFXML.fxml"));
```

However it just kept giving me the same problems. Thanks in advance.

My File Structure
https://gyazo.com/cec056fb358f453d32f49676bde12b5d

Comment: `Location not set` errors mean that the compiler could not find the FXML file you're referring to. I do see your FXML file is `loginFXML.fxml` but you're trying to load the file with a capital L: `LoginFXML.fxml`. This doesn't seem to have any effect in testing, but perhaps something happens with that when exporting?

Comment: Are you running on Windows, Linux or macOS ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I am running on Windows

Comment: @Zephyr I believe you have fixed my error, although it didn't seem to make any difference in intellij, when I exported it, the file names of the FXML files did seem to make a difference. Thank you so much for your comment, as you have saved me many hours of frustration.

Comment: Awesome, glad that helped! I added it as an answer. Feel free to accept it if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location not set` errors mean that the compiler could not find the FXML file you're referring to. I do see your FXML file is `loginFXML.fxml` but you're trying to load the file with a capital L: `LoginFXML.fxml`. This doesn't seem to have any effect in testing, but perhaps something happens with that when exporting?